# MVVM - How to wrap ViewModel in a ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, model, viewmodel

First of all, I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612027/mvvm-with-aggregated-model-classes-how-to-wrap-in-viewmodels) and did not find the answer for my problem.

I am not sure if this is an aggregated **Model** class or an aggregated **ViewModel** class, but this is what I have:

In my WPF (with Prism) application, I have a view '*Filter Customers View*' that connects to a service and requests a list of 'Customer' objects, based on a filter.

The list that is returned from the service is this :

```
List<CustomerDTO>    FilteredCustomers;
```

And the *CustomerDTO* looks like this:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
    public    Guid                CustomerId;
    public    String              Name;
    public    String              Address;
    public    String              PhoneNumber;
    public    OrderInfoDTO        LastOrderInformation;
    public    List<OtherClass>    ListOfSomething;
}
```

And the *OrderInfoDTO* looks like this:

```
public class OrderInfoDTO
{
    public    Guid          OrderId;
    public    DateTime      OrderDate;
    public    int           NumberOfProducts;
    public    double        TotalAmountSpent;
}
```

And the *OtherClass* looks like this:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public    Guid          Id;
    public    String        SomeText;
}
```

As you can see - the customer might or might not have a 'Last Order',

I would like to wrap the '*CustomerDTO*' object in a **ViewModel**,
so that I can bind it to the view.

This is what I thought of doing :

```
public class CustomerViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private CustomerDTO    _customerDTO;

    public CustomerViewModel(CustomerDTO   customerDTO)
    {
        _customerDTO = customerDTO;
    }

    public Guid CustomerId
    {
        get  {  return _customerDTO.CustomerId;  }
        set  {  _customerDTO.CustomerId = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerId "); }
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get  {  return _customerDTO.Name;  }
        set  {  _customerDTO.Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public String Address
    {
        get  {  return _customerDTO.Address;  }
        set  {  _customerDTO.Address = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Address"); }
    }

    public String PhoneNumber
    {
        get  {  return _customerDTO.PhoneNumber;  }
        set  {  _customerDTO.PhoneNumber= value; RaisePropertyChanged("PhoneNumber"); }
    }
}
```

.

**Questions:**

1. First of all - is 'CustomerDTO' what is known as a **Model** ? And is 'OrderInfoDTO' also a Model ? and what about 'OtherClass' ?
2. How do I treat the 'OrderInfoDTO' in my *CustomerViewModel* class ? Do I create a 'ViewModel' for it also ? where do I create the 'OrderInfoDTO' view-model ??? What happens if now someone updates the customer and sets the 'OrderInfoDTO' value ?
3. How do I treat the list of 'OtherClass' in my *CustomerViewModel* class ? Do I create an ObservableCollection for it ? What happens if someone will want to delete an item in it or update an item in it or add an item to it ?

Comment: WPF won't bind to fields.  Properties only.  So any POCO that has fields rather than properties cannot be used as a model.

Comment: Which class are you referring to ? My 'ViewModel' classes are not binded to POCOs !

Comment: My 'View' isn't binding to 'CustomerDTO' (the POCO). It is binded to 'CustomerViewModel' !

Comment: "First of all - is 'CustomerDTO' what is known as a Model?"  "WPF won't bind to fields. Properties only. So any POCO that has fields rather than properties cannot be used as a model."

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

1. The View is your UI that you would bind elements from the View Model to using the {Binding Path=, Mode=TwoWay -- If you want to update based upon the user input
2. The Model is only the data, this could a record set, file, database records etc.  So CustomerDTO and OrderInfoDTO are models.
3. The View Model is your link between the data (Model) and the UI (View).  It will allow to you change the data so it's easier to present on the UI

You would need to use ObservableCollection in all instances where there's a list that could change in the background.

You don't need a view model for OrderInfoDTO unless you need a view to update that data.  If you are presenting a CustomerDTO info with OrderInfoDTO in it, then making it a property of the CustomerDTO view model would be fine.